# Page Not Found Error on SharePoint Sites in TFS

Tags: sharepoint

I'm in big trouble here, today i was asked to add a new user to TFS, the first thing I do is adding it to SharePoint, but now every time I tried to enter the project portal (Team Explorer -> right click on project -> Show project portal) I got an page not found error, with every single project, Here are some basic info about the setup:

2 Tier TFS, TFS server, ReportServices and SharePoint are on the same server.

If I try to enter administration portal on this server (cd21vids1 is the tfs server)

http://cd21vids1:17012/ -- I get Directory Listing Denied

http://cd21vids1:17012/default.aspx  -- I get the default page, which works OK.

If i enter a project site i get this results (88 is the default port for SharePoint in this server):

http://cd21vids1:88/Sites/Cnbv.Framework/  -- Page not found

http://cd21vids1:88/Sites/Cnbv.Framework/default.aspx  --  I get the page but with no styles and the layout is wrong, also i get an error on the "remaining work" report (directory listing denied), the reports that have problems are "Issues List" and "Exit Criteria Status" (Directory Listing Denied on both cases).

Everything else seems to work OK, (builds, check-ins), I hope you can help me out, thanks.

Juan Zamudio

UPDATE: I did some more tests, i get a page not found error in the url

http://cd21vids1:88/Sites/Cnbv.Framework/_styles/core.css

Maybe this is way I get the default page without the correct layout.

UPDATE2: Also when I click the "Windows Sharepoint Services Site Administration" link I get this error: 
"The Team Foundation Server could not locate the online Site Administration application for this team project portal in Windows SharePoint Services. The most likely cause of this error is that the language settings on the team project portal do not match the current language of your Visual Studio client. The location of Site Administration is specific to the language of the project portal. Contact the Team Foundation Server administrator for availability information of Site Administration for this project portal. For more information, see the Windows SharePoint Services Administrator's Guide."

Someone changed the language to the server from English US to Spanish MX, I changed the language back to English and restarted the server but no dice (BTW I already had a folder named 2058 in "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\" like explained in this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/tfsadmin/thread/c224068a-0868-4e99-ad07-cb03f08dec4d/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my SharePoint problem is fixed, here are the details.

1. Run "SharePoint Product Technologies Configuration Wizard"
   1.1. Select do not disconnect from this server farm, click next
   1.2. Select No, this machine will continue to host the web site, click next.
   1.3 Click Next
2. Restart IIS

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem with the core.css file. I didn't want to use Sharepoint designer to solve it cause it would have unghosted my site!

So I tried this (it works) : on the site administration, go to "master page", and down the page you have a way to redefine the css used for the site. So i put there the url :/_layouts/1036/Styles/core.css  (1036= French, so use 1033 if you are site is in english!), and after validation it worked.

The problem is that the page still try to get the core.css from http://MYServeur/_styles/core.css ..and return a 404!

But at least I have my style back. I just post it in case... I still hope a real better solution...

AJ